# remove double quotes for only key in key=value pattern in python

Tags: python, json

I have json data which gets stored in format :

```
[{"Status": "status", "Command": "command", "IPAddress": "xx.xx.xx.xx ", "name": "name", "Service": "service"}]
```

which we will further modify to get :

```
"Status="status","Command="command","IPAddress="xx.xx.xx.xx","name="name","Service="service"
```

But I want  double-quotes (")  to be removed from key using python script .so expected output is like :

```
Status="status",Command="command",IPAddress="xx.xx.xx.xx",name="name",Service="service"
```

I am still new to python and really appreciate any help on this

Comment: No clear what you want to do with your input, could you clarify. Also, please explain what you already tried, so we can help you improve.

Comment: Is the output a *string*?

Comment: yes output is string .

Comment: i want the json data to be converted into my expected output , i have tried replacing special characters but got stuck with that double quote which remains at the beginning of every key like ("Status="status") so i want the double quotes to be removed from key

Comment: I would suggest deserialize the json then serialize to your own format.

Comment: @share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
j = [{"Status": "status", "Command": "command", "IPAddress": "xx.xx.xx.xx ", "name": "name", "Service": "service"}]
s = ""
for k,v in j[0].items():
    s += '{0}: "{1}", '.format(k, v)
print(s.rstrip(", "))
```

**Output:**

```
Status: "status", IPAddress: "xx.xx.xx.xx ", Command: "command", name: "name", Service: "service"
```

Comment: although it's my guess, the json in question probably is a string.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply , but how to remove , at the end of line :

Comment: Use `rstrip` just like in the solution

Comment: Status: "status", IPAddress: "xx.xx.xx.xx ", Command: "command", name: "name", Service: "service", 
The last , has to be removed

Comment: @Archana if the solution solved the problem. Please accept ans